# GoCD: How to set up pipelines dependencies

Tags: go-cd

I have two repositories (materials) git1 and git2.

On git1 commit I need pipeline to trigger, clone git2 repo, and perform some job. How to do it?

The problem is if I add git2 as a pipeline material, it would trigger on this material too, while I need to fetch git2 only to perform the job.

Answer (score 0):

You add both repositories as materials, and use the [ignore](https://docs.gocd.org/current/configuration/configuration_reference.html#ignore) filters `*` (all top-level files) and `**/*` (all files in subdirectories) in the second git repo:

```
<git url="https://github.com/somebody/repo2.git"
        dest="some-directory">
    <filter>
        <ignore pattern="*" />
        <ignore pattern="**/*" />
    </filter>
</git>
```

That way, the current version of repo2 will be checked out, but pushes to repo2 don't trigger a new build.